# flink checkpoint for a large source data

Tags: java, filesystems, state, apache-flink, checkpoint

I am using a flink streaming application with input source as nfs filesystem and sink as kafka producer.

I am using continousmonitoring function that forwards the file splits which doesnt support parllelism and continousFileOperator with parllelism.

The initial data that we have is 4TB of data. for initial transfer the continousmonitorfunction is taking long time to prepare the state which is ok, but the checkpoints keep expiring before they complete. I have changed the checkpointingTimeout to 3 hrs, still fails.

Can I know what consists of checkpointing state, does it matter with size of the data ?

Can I know how I can figure the size of the state would be ?

Is there any better way to do for a initial run with large data ?

Comment: How many files are there? I think that's much more likely to be the bottleneck.

Comment: Right now I am working with 3 million files in my test environment.There are more than that in prod. Is there a way I can force snapshot when files until a modification time is forwarded to continuousfileoperator?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that the reason for the poor performance is the large number of files being handled by a single instance of of the continousmonitoring function.

Rather than try to handle all of this with one instance of your pipeline, I would try having many independent pipelines, each with a source that handles a fraction of the files. This could be done in separate jobs, but that doesn't have to be the case: you can have a single job that contains many sources and sinks.